# Ios- Ipad- UicollectionViewCell- icon on a cell- how to add tap gesture to icon in xcode 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have used a collection view cell to display multiple images. Then each image will have a small icon on top right. My question is how to add a tap gesture to a small icon that's on top right of each cell image.

My code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(projectSetting:)];
_projectSettingIconButton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login-settings.png"]]; 
_projectSettingIconButton.frame = CGRectMake(95, 3, 21, 21); 
[_projectSettingIconButton addGestureRecognizer:tapped]; 
[cell addSubview:_projectSettingIconButton];
```

Comment: You have forgotten to add your code

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(projectSetting:)];

 _projectSettingIconButton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login-settings.png"]];
_projectSettingIconButton.frame = CGRectMake(95, 3, 21, 21);
[_projectSettingIconButton addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
[cell addSubview:_projectSettingIconButton];

Comment: By the by Thanks for coming to give a hand(helping me),.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This instead

Add tap Gesture Recogniser on the icon :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];        
[YOURICON addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Then Add

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(id)sender
{
    // do your stuff;
}
```

Comment: Is that icon a image view

Comment: If its only a icon then you can use a button with image and add the image of icon. It will be more easy if so